# Why weak reference couldn't be supported in ARC enabled platform?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

I'm re-reading ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) now.

In the beginning, it says

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit
>   applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not
>   supported in OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Why is this? Is implementing weak reference require deep down platform/OS support?

I thought, weak reference is not that special (considering C++ raw pointer usages).

Could it be not a technical reason? (weak reference support is dropped because it failed a few test cases and they don't have enough time?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weak references are self-zeroing. They are set to `nil` immediately before the object pointed to starts its `dealloc` and any attempt to assign an object that is in the middle of deallocating to a `weak` reference raises an exception. The runtime therefore needs to be able to store an addition mapping: from objects to any weak references to that object. iOS 4 did not implement that table.

The main implementation difference between them and C++'s `weak_ptr` is that there's no conversion step, as per the conversion to a `shared_ptr`. The `nil`ing is pushed, not pulled. The references can just be loaded as regular pointers at the machine level.

Part of the reason that the Objective-C runtime had to be extended to handle this is that Objective-C objects generally can't live on the stack. So tracking them automatically requires greater conspiracy between compiler and runtime. Unlike the STL, you wouldn't have seen ARC appear first as a third-party solution.

In practice it's just a few extra C calls that aren't implemented. The compiler support being in place, you can implement them yourself if you really want and support weak references under iOS 4 and earlier. Mike Ash did. Apple's decision was likely as much to do with its general attitude towards backward support for development technologies: it'd rather everyone use the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Weak properties are 'Zeroing Weak References', meaning that when the object is deallocated, all weak references to that object are automatically `nil`. The changes to the Objective C runtime necessary to make this work were not introduced until iOS5. ARC was allowed to work in iOS4 using `unsafe_unretained` in place of weak, which can become dangling pointers if the object they are pointing at is ever released.